# How does google.com redirect me to the correct language?

Tags: localization

If I enter www.google.com it is always in my language. How does google get the correct language? Do they check the IP or is the language of the browser?

Comment: My best bet is it looks at IP address, maps it to the country and shows the local page.

Comment: Try connecting through proxy with a different browser. It could possibly be a combination of things like IP address, route to your IP address, might as well be cookies, your search preferences...

Comment: I wish they got the correct language. I get often it in German, because our ISP is using German IP addresses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geolocation_software

Google uses IP  Geolocation to get information from what country you are browsing and tries to set you that language. Probably if it find other settings in the request header which also sends your browser language it will switch to it.

Comment: This (probably) isn't actually all that's going on - in multi-lingual countries it will be using the Accept-Language header too.  It's funny this post comes up as the google result for questions on the matter (already) since you'd figure they'd disclose just what they're doing somewhere in their docs.

Answer (score 3):

Your browser sends out [Accept-Language](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) header. Google is in english for me at work, where I have english OS+non-internationalized broser , but at home I got czech OS+browser and Google redirects me to google.cz.

Comment: Not true, I have an English OS and setted the preferred lang as English in the browser, and Google still sends me to www.google.com.ar (Argentina-Spanish) the first time (of course it remember my choice when I changed it)

Comment: @Eduardo - you're confusing localized search results with languages, not necessarily the same.  Google will always try and use the local version of it's search engine for the country you're in.  If you travel with a laptop, you'll find it redirects to the local version of google while you're there.

Answer (score 2):

It's your IP address which you get by your provider from where they conclude your geolocation and thus your language.

Answer (score 1):

Google knows all. They can probably pick out the clothes you like if you gave them the chance ;)

Its most likely a combination fo two things; geolocation via IP address, plus info gleaned from your google acocunt if you happen to be logged in.

Comment: They can probably tell what clothes you are wearing right now.

Comment: There's nothing to glorify with this, i think :)

Comment: Related: Proof Goole is God (http://www.thechurchofgoogle.org/Scripture/Proof_Google_Is_God.html) :D